# 'int' object not iterable after using hash on a dicitonary

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, set

I am trying to use set comprehension to get all unique values from a dictionary. The values are objects in a list. The dictionary looks like:

```
s = {
   "item1":[
      {
         "id":"integration_test_a",
         "version":"2020-09-18t17:00:04"
      },
      {
         "id":"integration_test_b",
         "version":"2020-09-24t05:58:38"
      },
      {
         "id":"integration_test_a",
         "version":"2020-09-24t06:01:06"
      }
   ],
   "item2":[
      {
         "id":"integration_test_a",
         "version":"2020-09-18t17:00:04"
      },
      {
         "id":"integration_test_a",
         "version":"2020-09-24t06:04:30"
      },
      {
         "id":"integration_test_c",
         "version":"2020-09-24t09:35:26"
      }
   ]
}
```

My attempt to do that :

```
filterList = {filter_ 
                for filterIds in hash(s.values())
                for filter_ in filterIds}
```

But I get an error:

```
    filterList = {filter_
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I know that the hash function converts s.values() into an integer but how do I use set comprehension to get the set of unique objects here?

Comment: What is your expected result? A set of `id`s from the lists?

Comment: @AndrejKesely oh no it is a set of unique objects like ```{{'id': '..', 'version': '...'}, {'id': '..', 'version': '...'}}```

Comment: Apart from the fact that you are hashing the whole dict_values object, which results in a single `int`, dictionaries can't be hashed.

Answer (score 2):

First, you usually never need to call `hash` directly; just putting things into a `set` or `dict` hashes them implicitly. Second, `dict` objects can't be hashed directly, you'll need to create an immutable representation of them first. You can of course convert back afterwards.

```
unique_items = set(frozenset(d.items()) for item in s.values() for d in item)
as_dict = [dict(i) for i in unique_items]
print(as_dict)
```

Produces:

```
[{'version': '2020-09-24t06:04:30', 'id': 'integration_test_a'}, 
 {'version': '2020-09-24t09:35:26', 'id': 'integration_test_c'}, 
 {'id': 'integration_test_b', 'version': '2020-09-24t05:58:38'}, 
 {'id': 'integration_test_a', 'version': '2020-09-24t06:01:06'}, 
 {'id': 'integration_test_a', 'version': '2020-09-18t17:00:04'}]
```

Comment: `tuple` can also be used, instead of `frozenset`.